# Mathematical logic: an example of a standard model of PA?

Tags: logic

Could someone provide an example of a standard model of Peano Arithmetic (PA), i.e., an example of a model of PA that is isomorphic to its intended model?

Comment: I feel like I'm missing the intent of your question, but the natural numbers are the intended model, where the sucessor of a number is it plus 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Any* "omega" sequence of objects gives us a model isomorphic to the standard model -- i.e. any bunch of objects will do which comes ordered in such a way that there is a first one, each object has a unique successor, and the chain of successors never circles back on itself. Just take the "numbers" in the model to be these objects, the "zero" to denote the first one in the ordering, the "successor" function to be the map that takes an object to the next one in the order (and then define "addition" and "multiplication" from "successor" to fit the equations of PA).

If you number off the members of your chosen omega sequence in the obvious way, numbering the "zero" by 0, its successor by 1, etc., you will set up an isomorphism with the standard model in the way Noah explains -- where the  standard model has the school-room numbers as the domain, zero as the first element, and with the familiar "next number" as the successor relation (and school-room addition and multiplication).

You can build omega sequences in all sort of ways -- starting with fiddling around with natural numbers (Noah has some suggestions, or just take the even numbers, etc.). Do you want a model that isn't built out of numbers? Then take the usual set-theoretic one. You start with the empty set as the zero, and then the successor of a number is the set comprising the numbers you have got so far -- so we get the familiar sequence $\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}, \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\}, \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}, \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\}\}, \ldots$ That gives us an omega sequence of the right kind.

Or do you want a more 'concrete' model? Well fix a  moment of time. Fix your and my centre of gravity then, as the spacetime points $s_0$ and $s_{\infty}$. Take the sequence, $s_0$, $s_1$ the halfway point between $s_0$ and $s_{\infty}$, $s_2$ the halfway point between $s_1$ and $s_{\infty}$, $s_3$ the halfway point between $s_2$ and $s_{\infty}$, etc., and give this sequence the natural ordering ...(if spacetime is dense, then there is such an omega sequence).

And so it goes ....

Answer (score 4):

The obvious standard model is exactly the intended model itself - namely, $(\mathbb{N}; +, \times)$. (I'm assuming here that $0\in\mathbb{N}$.)

How can we get others? Well, here's a few examples:

- Underlying set = nonpositive integers, $a\oplus b=a+b$, $a\otimes b=-a\cdot b$. (Here $\oplus$ and $\otimes$ refer to the "new" addition and multiplication, and $+$ and $\cdot$ to the usual addition and multiplication.) Basically, "flip the intended model around."
- Underlying set $\mathbb{N}\times \{17\}$ - so an element is an ordered pair $\langle n, 17\rangle$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Addition is given by $$\langle a, 17\rangle\oplus\langle b, 17\rangle=\langle a+b, 17\rangle,$$ and similarly for multiplication. Basically, "take the intended model and stick a $17$ on there for no reason."
- And there are lots of similar examples.

In each case, what we've done is defined a new underlying set together with a bijection with $\mathbb{N}$ ($x\mapsto -x$ in the first example, $x\mapsto \langle x, 17\rangle$  in the second example), and then "ported over" the usual structure on $\mathbb{N}$ to that new underlying set via the bijection. This is in fact exactly what isomorphism *means* - that there is a bijection such that the functions on one model are gotten by "porting over" the functions on the other model, along the bijection!